# VF : Page Parameters Query

Tags: visualforce

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/00Q/e?name_firstlea2=dsdf
```

The above URL helps me to create a new Lead with the first name already populated as "dsdf".

What i would like to know how this parameter "**name_firstlea2**" is mapped to "**FirstName**" of Lead.

I don't this mapping defined in SetUp.

Can someone tell me where am I supposed to see the mappings definition ?

Comment: AFAIK these parameters are not documented on purpose as they are not officially supported and liable to change at any time.

Comment: Also found this helpful: http://forcebydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Niks-PDF-SFDCIDs.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AdrianLarson says, not documented as subject to change. But, if you want to know what they are:

1. Open up a New Lead page
2. Open up Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug
3. Go to the HTML inspector (magnifying glass icon in Chrome tools)
4. Click on each input box to see the id used by SFDC OOB for the fields

[image]

As you can see, the field name for the URL for Company is `lea3`. It wouldn't take too much imagination to see SFDC changing this in Vx.0 to something like `company` and breaking your URL hack.

That said, URL hacking is irresistible as it gets results quickly. Be sure to document in your custom button description some maintenance notes for the person(s) following you.